# Stylesheets in XAMPP environment not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, xampp

I built a web application using XAMPP.

If I access it on another device in the network, the stylesheet is not working:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/LeadCapt/Res/style.css">
```

I guess I must have other links, not localhost...But which ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using relative url links instead of absolute url links.

Alternatively copy paste the href of CSS in browser URL to check whether it exists and is available at the location.